# Installed PWA keeps connecting to the old server after DNS update

Tags: progressive-web-apps, workbox

My domain [wheelofnames.com](https://wheelofnames.com) used to point to a web app hosted on Google App Engine. I made the app a Progressive Web App (PWA) using [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/). Two days ago I moved the app to Firebase Hosting, which meant I had to update the DNS record for my domain.

Today, users visiting wheelofnames.com from a web browser get their content served from Firebase Hosting. This is as expected, as the DNS record for that domain points to Firebase Hosting. Perfect!

But before the DNS update, I installed the PWA version of the app on my Android device. When I open that PWA today, it requests content from App Engine, even though the DNS record for wheelofnames.com doesn't point there any more. Checking the App Engine log, I see other users having the same experience.

How does one get the PWA to follow the DNS record and request content from the new environment instead of the old? Do PWAs cache DNS data somehow?

Answer (score 1):

The [Cache Storage API](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/cache-api) (which Workbox uses under the hood) uses request URLs as keys, and [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) objects as values.

While DNS resolution is important when making the requests to populate the caches initially, once a `Response` has been saved, reading the response and using it later on happens without regard to DNS resolution.

It sounds like you might need to kick off a new build for your web app and give Workbox's precaching a chance to pick up the changes to any updated files, which would be the case any time you make changes to precached content, irrespective of what host is used "under the hood". Also not that because precached content is shown in a cache-first manner, you may end up seeing previously cached content immediately when you revisit a site, and it's not until the next visit (after all tabs have been closed) that you'd see the fresh content.

There are UX patterns that can allow users to opt-in to seeing new content immediately, as described in [this recipe](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#offer_a_page_reload_for_users).

Answer (score -1):

its because subscriptions data are old. users should update their subscriptions.